# Generate between two dates in different rows SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on generating lines depending on the days (a row by day) between two dates. I would have in the first row the first date and in the second row the second date but it all depends on the ID and the money. I consider it is better to show you with an example:

The origin table:

[image]

My target:

[image]

Could be possible with a loop?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please don't post images of data.  Makes it hard for someone to test

Comment: you should be able to do that with analytic/window functions, but not sure about the specifics.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH dt_range ( id, dt, next_dt, money ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         dt,
         LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt),
         money
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         next_dt,
         money
  FROM   dt_range
  WHERE  dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY < next_dt
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY dt SET dt_order
SELECT id, dt, money FROM dt_range;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, dt, money ) AS
SELECT 500, DATE '2017-02-23',  3500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 500, DATE '2017-02-26', 35000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 500, DATE '2017-02-28', 50000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, DATE '2020-05-01',  8888 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, DATE '2020-05-05',   999 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, DATE '2020-05-09',  1000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | DT | MONEY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 500 | 23-FEB-17 | 3500 |
> | 500 | 24-FEB-17 | 3500 |
> | 500 | 25-FEB-17 | 3500 |
> | 500 | 26-FEB-17 | 35000 |
> | 500 | 27-FEB-17 | 35000 |
> | 500 | 28-FEB-17 | 50000 |
> | 200 | 01-MAY-20 | 8888 |
> | 200 | 02-MAY-20 | 8888 |
> | 200 | 03-MAY-20 | 8888 |
> | 200 | 04-MAY-20 | 8888 |
> | 200 | 05-MAY-20 | 999 |
> | 200 | 06-MAY-20 | 999 |
> | 200 | 07-MAY-20 | 999 |
> | 200 | 08-MAY-20 | 999 |
> | 200 | 09-MAY-20 | 1000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2567bdc76546ee2324712824f31da297)*

---

If you are using Oracle 11g then it has bugs iterating over dates; this can be easily fixed by iterating over a number and then adding it to a date (rather than iterating directly on the date):

```sql
WITH dt_range ( id, dt, offset, next_dt, money ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         dt,
         0,
         LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt),
         money
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         dt,
         offset + 1,
         next_dt,
         money
  FROM   dt_range
  WHERE  dt + offset + 1 < next_dt
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY dt SET dt_order
SELECT id, dt + offset AS dt, money FROM dt_range;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e57d32c109a3b7b57dbd672ec24f0fe1)*

Answer (score 1):

for example:

```
with 
simple_data( id,dates,money) as
(
select 500, date '2017-02-23',  3500 from dual union all
select 500, date '2017-02-26', 35000 from dual union all
select 500, date '2017-02-28', 50000 from dual union all
select 200, date '2020-05-01',  8888 from dual union all
select 200, date '2020-05-05',   999 from dual union all
select 200, date '2020-05-09',  1000 from dual
)
,step1 as 
(
select
  sd.id,
  sd.money,
  sd.dates,
  lead (dates,1,dates) over(partition by id order by dates)-1 lead_dts
from simple_data sd
)
select 
  st1.id,
  st1.dates + to_number(t.column_value)-1   as dates,
  st1.money
from step1 st1,table(cast(multiset(select level  from dual connect by level<= st1.lead_dts-st1.dates+1) as ora_mining_varchar2_nt)) t 
order by id desc,dates;

----OR------

with 
    simple_data( id,dates,money) as
    (
        select 500, date '2017-02-23',  3500 from dual union all
        select 500, date '2017-02-26', 35000 from dual union all
        select 500, date '2017-02-28', 50000 from dual union all
        select 200, date '2020-05-01',  8888 from dual union all
        select 200, date '2020-05-05',   999 from dual union all
        select 200, date '2020-05-09',  1000 from dual
    )
    ,step1 as 
    (
        select
          sd.id,
          sd.money,
          sd.dates,
          lag (dates,1,dates) over(partition by id order by dates desc) lag_dts
        from simple_data sd
    )
    select 
      st1.id,
      st1.lag_dts - to_number(t.column_value)   as dates,
      st1.money
    from step1 st1,table(cast(multiset(select st1.lag_dts-st1.dates - level +1  from dual connect by level<= st1.lag_dts-st1.dates) as ora_mining_varchar2_nt)) t 
    order by id desc,dates;
```

12c and later:

```
with 
simple_data( id,dates,money) as
(
select 500, date '2017-02-23',  3500 from dual union all
select 500, date '2017-02-26', 35000 from dual union all
select 500, date '2017-02-28', 50000 from dual union all
select 200, date '2020-05-01',  8888 from dual union all
select 200, date '2020-05-05',   999 from dual union all
select 200, date '2020-05-09',  1000 from dual
)
,step1 as 
(
select
  sd.id,
  sd.money,
  sd.dates,
  lead (dates,1,dates) over(partition by id order by dates)-1 lead_dts
from simple_data sd
)
select 
  st1.id,
  st1.dates + t.lvl-1   as dates,
  st1.money
from step1 st1,lateral(select level lvl  from dual connect by level<= st1.lead_dts-st1.dates+1) t
order by id desc,dates;

---OR-----

with 
simple_data( id,dates,money) as
(
select 500, date '2017-02-23',  3500 from dual union all
select 500, date '2017-02-26', 35000 from dual union all
select 500, date '2017-02-28', 50000 from dual union all
select 200, date '2020-05-01',  8888 from dual union all
select 200, date '2020-05-05',   999 from dual union all
select 200, date '2020-05-09',  1000 from dual
)
,step1 as 
(
select
  sd.id,
  sd.money,
  sd.dates,
  lag (dates,1,dates) over(partition by id order by dates desc) lag_dts
from simple_data sd
)
select 
  st1.id,
  st1.lag_dts - t.lvl   as dates,
  st1.money
from step1 st1,lateral(select st1.lag_dts-st1.dates - level +1 lvl  from dual connect by level<= st1.lag_dts-st1.dates ) t
order by id desc,dates;
```